# Wordpress: Blurry images when loading the page for first time

Tags: php, wordpress, image

When first time opening http://plenuum.com/ the images are blurry and become sharp only after a Command+R.

I've tried but could not fix it with WP plugins.

Any idea how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: So finally I've found the problem. I had to turn off the caching and the image resizing in the WP theme. 

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you found a solution :)

Answer (score 2):

On first load you are getting the file `wp-content/uploads/product1_v2-uai-258x506.png`, on the second you are getting the file `wp-content/uploads/product1_v2.png`. This is probably the fault of a caching plugin trying to save space by compressing images.

A quick fix might be to delete/rename the file `product1_v2-uai-258x506.png` and Wordpress may automatically fetch the larger file for you.

Comment: Thank you, James, for your help. I've removed the files and uploaded them again, deactivated a plugin which compressed the images but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little old but for Wordpress v4 try something like this

> THEME_NAME -> Theme Options -> Performance -> change Adaptive Images
>   settings or turn it off